# Toggle class on a set of elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, class, toggle

I have this mark-up:

```
<div> TEXT <a class="toggle-action"> TOGGLE </a></div>
<dl class="collapsed">
  ...

</dl>
<dl class="collapsed">
  ...
</dl>
```

When I click on the toggle link, all the `<dl>` elements below should toggle their class from expanded to collapsed and back. But only the first level of DLs, because some of them might have `DD` elements with other DLs...

How can I do this with javascript?

I know how to do it with jQuery, but I'd like to avoid it because it adds too much load just for this thing.

Currently I have this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){

  // my link
  if(e.target.className.indexOf('toggle-action') !== -1){
     // here how to select DLs?
  }

});
```

:)

Comment: well that is not much of a try. maybe show us how you would do this with jQuery at least for the *effort* checkmark

Comment: jQuery has the answer to this. http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ As it's free software, you can take a look how that is done wihtin their sources if you don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the following link:-
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/code/217121/changing-the-classname

Its trying to do similar stuff like you but in js